# How to format pointers using fmt library?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, formatting, fmt

I'm taking up some folks advice and looking into the fmt library:
http://fmtlib.net

It appears to have the features I need, and claims to support `%p` (pointer), but when compiling my code which uses a %p I get a long string of template errors (incomprehensible).  I'll post them at the end of this.

if I pull out the `%p` and the corresponding pointer argument, then it compiles on VS2017 c++17.

However, I'm at a loss as to how to either decode the template errors, or to get some insight as to why it won't accept a `%p` argument in the first place.

I've tried casting the argument to a `(void*)` - same issue.
I've tried using the python style syntax in the formatter `{}` - same issue.
I've broken out the %p bits separately from the rest of the formatting - same issue.

I see that there is support for user-types - but in this case I just want to output this as a raw pointer value.  I could just skip it, after all how valuable can the pointer address be, really?  But of course that means more work during conversion from `sprintf` to `fmt::format` to hunt down all %p and "do something with them" such as elide them.

But the docs seem to indicate that %p is supported - http://fmtlib.net/latest/syntax.html (about 3/4 of the way down - search on 'pointer' or 'p').

Here's the calling function: (note: `pAccels` is declared as `const ACCEL *`)

```
    m_hAccel = ::CreateAcceleratorTable(const_cast<LPACCEL>(pAccels), (int)count);
    if (!m_hAccel)
    {
        auto error = GetLastError();
        throw CWinAPIErrorException(__FUNCTION__, "CreateAcceleratorTable", fmt::format("%p,%u", pAccels, count), error);
    }
```

Here's the diagnostic spewage:

```
1>c:\users\steve\source\fmt\include\fmt\core.h(1073): error C2825: 'fmt::v5::internal::get_type<Context,Arg>::value_type': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Context=fmt::v5::basic_format_context<std::back_insert_iterator<fmt::v5::internal::buffer<char>>,char>,
1>            Arg=const ACCEL *
1>        ]
1>c:\users\steve\source\fmt\include\fmt\core.h(1081): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'fmt::v5::internal::get_type<Context,Arg>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Context=fmt::v5::basic_format_context<std::back_insert_iterator<fmt::v5::internal::buffer<char>>,char>,
1>            Arg=const ACCEL *
1>        ]
1>c:\users\steve\source\fmt\include\fmt\core.h(1190): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned __int64 fmt::v5::internal::get_types<Context,const ACCEL*,size_t>(void)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Context=fmt::v5::basic_format_context<std::back_insert_iterator<fmt::v5::internal::buffer<char>>,char>
1>        ]
1>c:\users\steve\source\fmt\include\fmt\core.h(1190): note: while compiling class template member function 'unsigned __int64 fmt::v5::format_arg_store<fmt::v5::basic_format_context<std::back_insert_iterator<fmt::v5::internal::buffer<Char>>,Char>,const ACCEL *,size_t>::get_types(void)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Char=char
1>        ]
1>c:\users\steve\source\fmt\include\fmt\core.h(1478): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'fmt::v5::format_arg_store<fmt::v5::basic_format_context<std::back_insert_iterator<fmt::v5::internal::buffer<Char>>,Char>,const ACCEL *,size_t>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Char=char
1>        ]
1>c:\users\steve\source\tbx\wapi\acceleratortable.cpp(58): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> fmt::v5::format<char[6],const ACCEL*,size_t,0>(const S (&),const ACCEL *const &,const size_t &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            S=char [6]
1>        ]
1>c:\users\steve\source\fmt\include\fmt\core.h(1073): error C2510: 'value_type': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
1>c:\users\steve\source\fmt\include\fmt\core.h(1073): error C2065: 'type_tag': undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\steve\source\fmt\include\fmt\core.h(1073): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
1>c:\users\steve\source\fmt\include\fmt\core.h(1073): note: a non-constant (sub-)expression was encountered
1>c:\users\steve\source\fmt\include\fmt\core.h(1197): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
1>c:\users\steve\source\fmt\include\fmt\core.h(1082): note: failure was caused by non-constant arguments or reference to a non-constant symbol
1>c:\users\steve\source\fmt\include\fmt\core.h(1082): note: see usage of 'value'
```

Comment: You have to cast to `void*` first.

Comment: Have you tested to see if `%p` is totally broken for pointers?  What if you gave it a plain old `int *`?  What would happen?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To format a pointer you can either cast it to `void*`:

```cpp
std::string s = fmt::format("{},{}", static_cast<void*>(pAccels), count);
```

or wrap it in `fmt::ptr`:

```cpp
std::string s = fmt::format("{},{}", fmt::ptr(pAccels), count);
```

Working example on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/sCNbjr

Note that `format` uses Python-like format string syntax, not `printf`'s and returns a `std::string` object.

Comment: It also supports printf style %s and etc.  At least the docs say as much.
I did try casting `pAccels` to `void*` and hit the same issue.  But I hadn't run CMake - which might resolve this.

Comment: Yes, but for `%s` you need to use `fmt::sprintf`, not `fmt::format`.

Comment: You don't need CMake, check out the godbolt link that uses vanilla MSVC. The error might be because you are passing std::string to an API requiring a C string, not pointer formatting.

Comment: Not sure why - either I was tired, or the compiler was flagging later invocations of `format()` as erroneous due to previous invocations that it did not issue an error on?  Dunno.  At any rate, simply casting to `void*` was the trick.  I needed to cast other handles to either `void*` or `UINT_PTR` depending on if I was trying to output them as `%p` or `%X`, respectively.